# Customizing of installation process, not package set at install

Tags: system-installation, gparted, boot-partition

How and where can I get access to source code of the Ubuntu installation scripts?

I've opened the ISO file for my desired distro, and everything appears to be binaries, and no modifiable scripts.

I would like to specifically modify logic and sequence at the point where it tries to identify/choose a partition/disk to install because I have a multi-purpose disk for which I do not want to have the install wipe out as a single-partition disk, and the best alternative offered will only allow install over the existing target partition's contents, not give specific option to re-install fresh to a freshly reformatted 1st partition.

Note other existing hard drives intentionally not chosen for functional purposes.

Comment: Partitions were existing, not newly created.   Size=300 GB

Comment: The distro install process, even with Ubuntu 20.04, does not present info/requests related to a chosen partition all at once, to give confidence that the desired action will take place.   It is desired that a radio button be on the partition selection screen that would allow the installer to specify "Wipe/delete partition contents before installing new distro image."   The other interraction prompts are OK.

Comment: `gparted` is usually part of the installation process. What you are suggesting is a user interface design change. It's an enhancement request to the developers of Ubuntu so off-topic here. **Voting to Close**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a Ubuntu Installation design enhancement request.